# How to make Network Manager ignore VMware virtual network adapters

Tags: networking, network-manager, vmware

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, fully updated.

The 2 devices listed that are not being managed didn't show up until I installed VMware Workstation 12.1.1. I believe they are from the VMware host-only/NAT virtual networking devices (VMnet1 & VMnet8). How can I get them out of this menu?

See screenshot here:

[image]

They don't show up in the network connections dialog:

[image]

Anyone else have this issue and/or know of a solution?

Results of the nmcli command:

```
$ nmcli dev status
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION
enp7s0  ethernet  connected    enp7s0
enp8s0  ethernet  unavailable  --
vmnet1  ethernet  unmanaged    --
vmnet8  ethernet  unmanaged    --
lo      loopback  unmanaged    --
```

MAC Addresses of the vmnet* devices:

```
$ LANG=c ifconfig vmnet1|grep HWaddr
vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:01

$ LANG=c ifconfig vmnet8|grep HWaddr
vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:08
```

I've already tried modifying /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf with the following additions:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:00:50:56:c0:00:01;mac:00:50:56:c0:00:08
```

Then ran:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

However, I still see the 2 devices in the list when I click on the applet.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found a temporary workaround, but still can't find a way to get Network Manager to ignore my VMware virtual networking adapters.  I fixed it by removing the virtual networking adapters within VMware.  The only one remaining is the bridged one, which coincidentally, Network Manager doesn't see or show in the list from the indicator drop-down in the OP.